# what does "drop one's balls" mean?

Tags: word-meaning, idioms, slang

I see it in "Regular Show"

The whole sentence : Benson's gonna ***drop his balls*** when he sees how good we set up these chairs.

Is it a slang ? I haven't found anything in web.

Comment: I think that's equivalent to [(one's) jaw drops](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/my+jaw+dropped), but in a slangy way.

Comment: See the following: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/195433/balls-have-dropped-what-does-it-mean